# can we update imagemosaic layer with geoserver rest api?

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, geoserver-rest-api

I am new to GIS and geoserver. I am trying to add and modify imagemosaic layers to geoserver with geoserver rest api. Actually I could add the layers. But I have modify them with rest api while adding or after adding. The parameters I have to set is:

Layer name, srs handling, declared rss, background values, use jai image read

Can I set these values with rest api? If there is documentation about it i will read but I couldn't find any. And if we can set these values I have to solve out how?

Thanks,,

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via the REST interface by posting to the right URL as indicated here:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/coverages.html#workspaces-ws-coveragestores-cs-coverages-c-format

the new XML representation for the coverage layer.
I would use the original one as a template to modify and post back to experiment.

As an alternative in java you can use the GeoServer-Manager as shown here:
https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager/wiki/Managing-Mosaic-Layers

Simone.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the cURL API REST documentation :

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#uploading-and-modifying-a-image-mosaic

Regards,

Comment: Sadly, link no longer works

Comment: The URL was edited ;)